# Missed comma between flow collection entries when using Fn::GetAtt in YAML

Tags: yaml, serverless-framework, serverless, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm trying to add an event stream for DynamoDB in YAML, DynamoDB table is a variable that changes based on
the environment it gets deployed to, I'm using `Fn::GetAtt` to determine `TABLE_NAME` but it's giving me an exception.

1. Is the syntax right?
2. Is there a way to configure the stream in YAML other than `Fn::GetAtt` ?

**Exception:**

```
missed comma between flow collection entries in "erverless.yml" at line 60, 
column28:Fn::GetAtt: [ ${self:custom.TABLE_NAME ...
```

**Code:**

```
  custom:
      TABLE_NAME : mix of account + env + name
  events:
  - stream:
      type: dynamodb
      arn:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ ${self:custom.TABLE_NAME}, StreamArn ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside YAML flow collections, strings with characters like `{`, `}`, `[` etc. have to be quoted, because `{` starts a flow mapping and `[` starts a flow sequence.
There is no space required for that.
So this is how it should look like:

```yaml
      arn:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ '${self:custom.TABLE_NAME}', StreamArn ]
```

For information on pretty much all types of quoting in YAML you can have a look at https://www.yaml.info/learn/quote.html (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it.I started getting this error `Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute`

Comment: Should `StreamArn ` be surrounded with single quotes? or should it be arn value?

Comment: That's specific to the application, I don't know. But `StreamArn` shouldn't need quotes in any case.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response, what's the first parameter has to be? Is it a table name? or arn ?