# How to retrieve the first value from a comma separated string in using cloudformation intrinsic function

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-ssm

I have SSM Parameter with name `vpc-subnet-ids` and value is comma separated string like: "`subnet1,subnet2`"

I want to get the first subnet using serverless.yaml file.I am using this but this is not working:

```
SubnetId: !Split [",", !Ref ${ssm:/vpc-subnet-ids}[0]]
```

Tried this as well  `!Select [1, !Split [",", ${ssm:/vpc-subnet-ids}]]`. this is giving

```
missed comma between flow collection entries in
```

Serverless framework: 3.26.0

Answer (score 0):

I resolved your problem by adding single quotes, example shown below. I tested this and it works.

```
!Select [1, !Split [",", '${ssm:/vpc-subnet-ids}']]
```

Partial credit goes to this post: [Missed comma between flow collection entries when using Fn::GetAtt in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63820011/missed-comma-between-flow-collection-entries-when-using-fngetatt-in-yaml). It came up in a google search for the error you mentioned "`missed comma between flow collection entries in`"